# Magento - Transactional emails not displaying

Tags: email, magento, transactions

I am having a problem with creating an new email template in the Transaction Emails int he admin area.

In this section if I click Add New Template the drop down box for 'Template' is empty.

In the directory app/locale/en_US/template/email the relevant html files are there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you customized your core codes?

Comment: No I make local versions when I alter files. I have various modules I created but I haven't altered any of the core Magento files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't modify any core file then check your `core_email_template` table.
If this table is not empty the you need to debug